# Sorting a VARCHAR field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with just one column. There are over  16 million rows in this table. The table contains all the RGB color values closed by parentheses. For instance,
(100,155,255). However, they are unsorted. How do I sort such that the first row will be (0,0,0), the second row (0,0,1) etc and the last row be (255,255,255)? I have tried ORDER BY CAST which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what is the exact data sample  ..  ?? is a string with 3 value separated  by comma enclose in () ??

Comment: Store the R, G, and B values as separate columns, then `ORDER BY R, G, B`.

Comment: @scaisEdge, yes, exactly. Well, actually, 3 numbers, each of which can take a value between 0 and 255. Both limits included. Separated by (). Data sample: (139,111,107)
(140,111,107)
(141,111,107)
(142,111,107)
(143,111,107). These are actual, random rows from the table.

Comment: i have already posted  an answer  based on this assupmtion ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, indeed. I'm saving the output of that query to some text file. Can already hear the fans overloading. I'm hoping the first line will be (0,0,0), the second (0,0,1) and so on.

Comment: @scaisEdge, indeed. I'm saving the output of that query to some text file. I'm hoping the first line will be (0,0,0), the second (0,0,1) and so on.

Comment: @MugaS.  i don't understand your comment  .. have you tried  the code in my answer  or not ..?

Comment: @scaisEdge, I have and it's still running. We still have to wait for the query to complete though.

Comment: @MugaS. . 16 million  .. full scan is not a small number ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using cast on substring

```
SELECT your_column
from your_table 
order by CAST(replace( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( your_column, ',', 1), ',', -1) , '(','') AS UNSIGNED) 
   , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( your_column, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS UNSIGNED) 
   , CAST(replace(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( your_column, ',', 3), ',', -1), ')','') AS UNSIGNED)
```